# Eclipse shortcut to automatically declare the class and variable from method return type

Tags: eclipse

Does anybody know of a short cut in Eclipse that will put in the class and variable based on a method return type?

For e.g.

```
SomeClass{
  public AnotherClass getAnotherClass(){
  }
}

MainClass{
  someClassObj.getAnotherClass();// Short cut here to insert "AnotherClass anotherClass ="
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This shortcut exists: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> and then a second key press:

- <kbd>F</kbd> creates a new field
- <kbd>L</kbd> creates a new variable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is one, considering:

- it is generally considered "bad practice" to call a method returning a value without assigning this value to a variable.
  And if you assign it, you have your `AnotherClass anotherClass[=...]` set in the code directly ;)
- Even if you don't assign to a return value, you can move your mouse over the method to get its definition (including the return type).

Comment: I get the definition by moving the mouse over, but sometimes generated JAXB classes are so long that I hope I could do a ctrl + space to have it magically appear...:)

Comment: And, to make matters worse, there is always overloading!